# AngularJS ng-src in ie8: image not loaded and "unsafe" added to path

Tags: image, angularjs, internet-explorer-8, src, unsafe

I just wanted to add an image to my app.
As advised, I used the **ng-src** directive:

```
<img ng-src="{{app.imgBig}}" alt="lorem ipsum" height="100" width="200" title="lorem ipsum" />
```

It works fine on most browsers but it doesn't on IE8.
The image is not loaded as instead of adding the absolute url to the file name, it returns the relative path and adds "**unsafe:**" before it.

Actually, it's trying to load:

> unsafe:img/test.jpg

Instead of:

> http://url_of_my_site.com/img/test.jpg

So you know, it may be related to the fact I had to completely disable **SCE** to support IE7:

```
$sceProvider.enabled(false);
```

A quick fix was to create a base path constant and to add it at the beginning of the image path but it's not the best as the app shouldn't be dependent from this base path.

Any idea ?

Comment: From your description, if `unsafe:` is still being added, even with `$sceProvider.enabled(false)`, sounds like some use of `$sanitize` is still happening. May be related to a current AngularJS bug — check https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2901 for details and a possible fix.

Comment: Thanks for your help Alex but I tried the fix advised but **"unsafe:"** is still there:  
`var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [], function ($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*((https?|ftp|mailto):)|#/);
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution myself:

1. Get the current base url thanks to the Location object:

   ```
   var base_url = location.protocol + "//" + location.hostname + location.pathname;
   ```
2. Give it as a base path to my image in my controller:

   ```
   imgBig: base_url + 'img/' + $scope.imgBig
   ```

That way, **unsafe:** disappeared, it works on every browsers and it's independent from a constant base path.

Hope it can help !

Comment: You can mark this answer as accepted as it solved your problem. Accepting your own answer is acceptable in cases like this. Welcome to Stack Overflow!