# How to use img ng-src in AngularJS on android phone?

Tags: android, image, angularjs, src, angular-ui-bootstrap

The most relevant Q & A I've found is from [google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/NRutixKCQLY) and I've read the [AngularJS docs for `ngSrc`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc).

I'm trying to use [Angular UI Bootstrap - Carousel](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/carousel) in my app and I noticed the demo uses absolute URLs for slides like this: `image: 'http://placekitten.com/' + newWidth + '/300'`.

It works on my localhost (mac) but I don't think images (slides) display on my android google nexus phone because I only use relative image paths like this: `image: '/images/help/hello-1.jpg'`.

**How can I use relative image paths with `ng-src` directive without having `http://` on an android phone?** 
**Is using `$location` a possible solution ([from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21837851/angularjs-ng-src-in-ie8-image-not-loaded-and-unsafe-added-to-path))?**

**My html:**

```
<div ng-controller="helloCtrl" class="slide-container">
  <div>
    <carousel interval="myInterval">
      <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
        <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>{{slide.headline}}</h3>
          <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
          <a ng-href="mailto:help@help.com?subject=help-enquiry" class="menu_button"><p>Contact Us</p></a>
        </div>
      </slide>
    </carousel>
  </div>
</div>
```

**my js:**

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('helloApp');

app.controller('helloCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.slides = [
    {
      image: '/images/hello-1.jpg',
      headline: 'Help1',
      text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisic.'
    },
    {
      image: '/images/hello-2.jpg',
      headline: 'Help2',
      text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do.'
    }
  ];
});
```

Comment: Yes you can use relative paths. Whatever value you use for ng-src just get's parsed and put into the img src.  Have you even tried it out yet?  Do you have sample page that shows that it doesn't work how you expect?

Comment: Yes, on both localhost (mac) and android phone.  Works on mac. Not on google nexus phone. AFAIK, I can only take screenshots for that to debug missing images.

Comment: In that case, you may want to adjust your question to make it more clear that your issue is on an Android device.  You answered the current question (in the title) by saying that it does work on your mac.

Comment: Also, I think your issue might be more related to broken binding in Android with certain versions of angularjs (which version are you using?). [See this angularjs issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5323)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying and the link.  Using `Angular 1.2.6` so that should be resolved according to the comments.

Comment: @JoseM, Thanks for all of the help, I had to play around with file path to fix it.  Have you encountered my solution before of having to use one level file path in js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I could not use a file path with several directories like this `image: '/images/hello-1.jpg'` in my js.

**new html:**

```
...
<img ng-src="images/{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
...
```

**new js:**

```
...
    {
      image: 'hello-1.jpg',
      ...
    },
    {
      image: 'hello-2.jpg',
      ...
    }
  ...
```